# Do I need the "Pro" Paypal account to use the Payments API

Tags: javascript, paypal

As the title asks, do I need to have a "Pro" account to use the Payment API specifically the CreatePayment endpoint.

I do not want to use Paypal checkout, I simply want to use them to process payments from my site.

I know the "feature" list says customization and on-page check-out requires pro account, but I'm not sure if this is referring to their REST API.

So basically all I want to use is:

```
curl -v -X POST https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment \
-H "Content-Type:application/json" \
-H "Authorization: Bearer Access-Token" \
-d '{
  "intent": "sale",
  "payer": {
  "payment_method": "paypal"
  },
  "transactions": [
  {
    "amount": {
    "total": "30.11",
    "currency": "USD",
    "details": {
      "subtotal": "30.00",
      "tax": "0.07",
      "shipping": "0.03",
      "handling_fee": "1.00",
      "shipping_discount": "-1.00",
      "insurance": "0.01"
    }
    },
    "description": "This is the payment transaction description.",
    "custom": "EBAY_EMS_90048630024435",
    "invoice_number": "48787589673",
    "payment_options": {
    "allowed_payment_method": "INSTANT_FUNDING_SOURCE"
    },
    "soft_descriptor": "ECHI5786786",
    "item_list": {
    "items": [
      {
      "name": "hat",
      "description": "Brown color hat",
      "quantity": "5",
      "price": "3",
      "tax": "0.01",
      "sku": "1",
      "currency": "USD"
      },
      {
      "name": "handbag",
      "description": "Black color hand bag",
      "quantity": "1",
      "price": "15",
      "tax": "0.02",
      "sku": "product34",
      "currency": "USD"
      }
    ],
    "shipping_address": {
      "recipient_name": "Hello World",
      "line1": "4thFloor",
      "line2": "unit#34",
      "city": "SAn Jose",
      "country_code": "US",
      "postal_code": "95131",
      "phone": "011862212345678",
      "state": "CA"
    }
    }
  }
  ],
  "note_to_payer": "Contact us for any questions on your order.",
  "redirect_urls": {
  "return_url": "http://www.amazon.com",
  "cancel_url": "http://www.hawaii.com"
  }
}'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on how strictly you define "*my site*".

You do **not** need a Pro account to process payments by directing the visitor to PayPal through either a [**button redirect**](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/button_summary/) or a [**popup**](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/ht_ap-embeddedPayment-curl-etc/).

You **will** need a Pro account (**and SSL**) to process the payments directly from you own page with the [**Express Checkout**](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/products/express-checkout/), providing a truly 'seamless' payment.

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: My site will most definitely be using SSL. I have no interest in adding a popup or button. I have a credit card form on my site that I want to use.   "Express Checkout is a solution for merchants who currently accept credit card payments online and would like to add PayPal as a payment option." This is not my scenario, I do not currently accept payments, but I want to accept credit card.

Comment: In order to accept Credit Cards that are **processed** through PayPal, you unfortuantely need a Pro Account. It sounds like you're looking for [PayPal Payments Pro](https://www.paypal.com/us/webapps/mpp/paypal-payments-pro).

Comment: Thank you @Obsidian Age, that is the information I was looking for.